# Prevent Duplicate E-mail Address Submissions c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following c# code below that I am trying to include additional functionality to prevent duplicate e-mail addresses from being entered into the database using an asp.net form. Below is the code, currently it is inserting all entries, duplicate or not, into the database.

```
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Configuration;

public partial class Default2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["northwind"].ToString();
        con.Open();
        string query = "SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM Table1 WHERE pEmail=' " + TextBox2.Text + "'";
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, con);
    int count = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

    if (count > 0)
        {
            Label1.Text = "email is already in use";
        }
        else {
        cmd.CommandText = "insert into[Table1](pName, pEmail)values(@nm,@em)";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nm", TextBox1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@em", TextBox2.Text);
        cmd.Connection = con;
        int a = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        if (a>0)
            {
                Label1.Text = "Inserted Sucessfully!";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Asp.net form code

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div style="height: 138px">

    Enter Name:<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" style="margin-left: 12px"></asp:TextBox>

    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator 
id="reqName" 
ControlToValidate="TextBox1"
Style="color:Red"   
ErrorMessage="Please enter your name!"
runat="server"  />

    <br />
    Enter Email:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator 
id="ValidEmail" 
ControlToValidate="TextBox2" 
Style="color:Red"
ValidationExpression="^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$"
ErrorMessage="Invalid Email Entry" 
runat="server" />

    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Submit" />
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>

</div>
</form>
```

Comment: You define the argument `@TextBox2`, but you never add it to the command `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TextBox2", TextBox2.Text);`. And there are a few issues within the `else` block you should take a look at...

Comment: @VDWWD I think I might have specified the wrong argument. TextBox2 is the name of the text box on the asp.net form where the e-mail would be. Could that be why? pEmail is the ID of the associated with the entry in TextBox2. Should I provide the form code?

Comment: I think your ASP.NET form is alright. Can you put a breakpoint after `query` is set and see what the value of `TextBox2.Text` is in the `query` string? And then confirm that you're getting the right results back in the `reader`?

Comment: I added a breakpoint for query using Visual Studio and I got "An exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: No value given for one or more required parameters." I am very new to using visual studio however.

Comment: You got the exception at the breakpoint? Or somewhere else? Can you see if `TextBox2.Text` has a value?

Comment: I am so new to VS, when I set the breakpoint it was saying that the variable could not be found. I actually adjusted the code to the above, because I realized I had "TextBox2" specified. When I ran it through the debugger TextBox2.Text would display the "@em" so the data posts to the database, it just posts even if it's duplicated. I could actually see the e-mail passing through the query but for some reasons it always passes on to the successful insertion.

Comment: Get your SQL OUT OF THE PAGE!!! And, add a `unique` constraint to the table on the emailaddress column.

Comment: You also need to wrap your SQL objects in a `using() {}` block, or call `.Dispose` when you're done with it. This thing will leak like crazy, and is really terrible design. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are a doing a `SELECT` statement, you need to the [ExecuteScalar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx) method on `OleDbCommand` to get the results. As per the MSDN documentation, ExecuteScalar returns:

> The first column of the first row in the result set, or a null
>   reference if the result set is empty.

In your case, the return will be the value of `COUNT(ID)` from your query.

[ExecuteNonQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx) is for operations which modify data and will return the number of rows affected by the query. As per the MSDN documentation:

> You can use the ExecuteNonQuery to perform catalog operations, for
>   example, to query the structure of a database or to create database
>   objects such as tables, or to change the data in a database without
>   using a DataSet by executing UPDATE, INSERT, or DELETE statements.
>   Although the ExecuteNonQuery returns no rows, any output parameters or
>   return values mapped to parameters are populated with data. For
>   UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the number
>   of rows affected by the command. For all other types of statements,
>   the return value is -1. If a rollback occurs, the return value is also
>   -1.

So change you code as follows:

```
string query = "SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM Table1 WHERE pEmail='" + TextBox2.Text + "'"; // note: vulnerable to SQLInjection.
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);
int count = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

if (count > 0)
{
  // etc.
```

**Update:** I would also recommend using a [Transaction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/93ehy0z8(v=vs.110).aspx) on your operation to make sure that a duplicate email address is not added in between your checking for duplicates and you doing the actual insert.

**Update 2:**
Based on the updated code that switches to using ExecuteScalar, this line:

```
string query = "SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM Table1 WHERE pEmail=' " + TextBox2.Text + "'";
```

Should be:

```
string query = "SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM Table1 WHERE pEmail='" + TextBox2.Text + "'";
```

(Extra whitespace character between `pEmail='` and `"` removed.

Comment: With this I get "System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: No value given for one or more required parameters." on int count = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

Comment: That's because you need to fix your generated query to be `string query = "SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM Table1 WHERE pEmail=' " + TextBox2.Text + "'";` like in the other answers.

Comment: Both entries, duplicates or not get added to the database still.

Comment: @penmas, please update your question with your latest code then. Stop making this a guessing game for everyone!

Comment: I apologize! Updating now!

Comment: @penmas, looks like there is an extra whitespace character in the query I gave you in the comment. Please see my updated answer and fix.

Answer (score 1):

I think it may be the way you're instantiating the command object, but I'm not in a place to set up a test project to confirm. I think you actually want the `ExecuteReader` method, or at least that's what I've used in the past for `SELECT` on the fly like this.

This is what I'm basing it on: [OleDbCommand.ExecuteReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/979byfca(v=vs.110).aspx)

Can you try something like

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
 OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();
 con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["NorthwindConnectionString2"].ToString();
 con.Open();
 string query = "SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM Table1 WHERE pEmail= " + TextBox2.Text;
 OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, con);
 OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

 int count = 0;

 while (reader.Read()) {
  count = Convert.ToInt32(reader[0].ToString());
 }
 reader.Close();

 if (count > 0) {
  Label1.Text = "email is already in use";
 } else {
  //re-instantiate the command obj
  cmd = new OleDbCommand();  //empty constructor should work, I think
  cmd.CommandText = "insert into[Table1](pName)values(@nm)";
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nm", TextBox1.Text);
  cmd.CommandText = "insert into[Table1](pEmail)values(@nm)";
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nm", TextBox2.Text);
  cmd.Connection = con;
  int a = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  if (a > 0) {
   Label1.Text = "Inserted Sucessfully!";
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I made this adjustment and actually if there are still duplicate entities I get the successfully submitted notification.  Could it be an issue with my logic?

Comment: TextBox2 is the name of the text box on the asp.net form where the e-mail would be. Could that be why? pEmail is the ID of the associated with the entry in TextBox2. Perhaps this is the issue?

Comment: I did not downvote any of these! I will upvote them to see if that helps.

Comment: Updated the query string to use your TextBox2.Text value -- can you try this?

Comment: I updated it & I got the "Inserted Successfully" message. Perhaps it is my form, I will post it.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to check if the email exist with these lines:

```
string query = "SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM Table1 WHERE pEmail= @TextBox2";
int count = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(query);
```

but you don't use ExecuteNonQuery to get data from the database, you use ExecuteReader.

Hope this help you with yout issue.

Comment: If you are going to downvote, at least you should say why ¬¬

Comment: I did not downvote! However, I updated code to include this and there are no errors but when  I add the same e-mail address it still adds it to database. Can ideas on what would be the issue? I have specified the wrong logic somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

**ExecuteNonQuery** does not take an argument. Try this:

```
string query = "SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM Table1 WHERE pEmail= @TextBox2";
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query);
int count = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Also, you are trying to check the return value of **ExecuteNonQuery** which actually returns the number of rows affected. But that is not the value returned by you SQL statement. If you would like to get the value returned by your SQL statement, you should use **ExecuteReader** or **ExecuteScalar**.

And I am not sure if your query is correct either. Shouldn't it be something like:

```
string query = "SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM Table1 WHERE pEmail= " + TextBox2.Text;
```